# Pandas assign - passing column in a user defined function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given an input dataframe and string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [10, 20, 30], "B" : [0, 1, 8]})
colour = "green" #or "red", "blue" etc.
```

I want to add a new column `df["C"]` conditional on the values in `df["A"]`, `df["B"]` and `colour` so it looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [4, 2, 10], "B" : [1, 4, 3], "C" : [True, True, False]})
```

So far, I have a function that works for just the input values alone:

```
def check_passing(colour, A, B):
    if colour == "red":
        if B < 5:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if colour == "blue":
        if B < 10:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    if colour == "green":
        if B < 5:
            if A < 5:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```

How would you go about using this function in `df.assign()` so that it calculates this for each row? Specifically, how do you pass each column to `check_passing()`?

`df.assign()` allows you to refer to the columns directly or in a lambda, but doesn't work within a function as you're passing in the entire column:

```
df = df.assign(C = check_passing(colour, df["A"], df["B"]))
```

Is there a way to avoid a long and incomprehensible lambda? Open to any other approaches or suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying a function like that can be inefficient, especially when dealing with dataframes with many rows. Here is a one-liner:

```
colour = "green" #or "red", "blue" etc.

df['C'] = ((colour == 'red') & df['B'].lt(5)) | ((colour == 'blue') & df['B'].lt(5)) | ((colour == 'green') & df['B'].lt(5) & df['A'].lt(5))
```